# Why I cannot map a texture to an object in Three.js?

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping

Here is my code working partially: https://jsitor.com/Ztz8xPdezJ

I tried hard almost two days but I could not get it run.

I was expecting the texture of rock images mapped to the head object but I guess I only get average of the texture colors mapped on the the face object.

I can also add code here, but it cannot ru here since it needs Javascript module.

```js
import * as THREE from 'https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js';

import { OrbitControls } from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';


var scene = new THREE.Scene();


var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 4 / 3, .1, 500)
camera.position.set(240, 240, 240);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);


var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor(0xdddddd);
renderer.setSize(800, 600);
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;


var tl = new THREE.TextureLoader();

var texture = tl.load('https://threejs.org/examples/models/json/lightmap/rocks.jpg');

const loader = new THREE.BufferGeometryLoader();

// load a resource
loader.load(
  // resource URL
  // '/3D/models/WaltHeadLo_buffergeometry.json',
  'https://threejs.org/examples/models/json/WaltHeadLo_buffergeometry.json',
  // onLoad callback
  function (geometry) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0xcccccc, map: texture });
    var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    object.name = "head";
    scene.add(object);
  },

  // onProgress callback
  function (xhr) {
    console.log( 'loaded');
  },

  // onError callback
  function (err) {
    console.log('An error happened');
  }
);
  

var spotLight1 = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
spotLight1.name =  "SpotLight1";
spotLight1.position.set(150, 300, 500);
spotLight1.castShadow = true;
scene.add(spotLight1);



var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
renderer.render(scene, camera);




const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);



animate();

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<html>


<body>
    <div id="canvas" width="800px" height="600px"></div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

also add my code here:

Comment: Your question requires more details, including the expected vs. actual results, and any errors you are receiving. Also, please incude your code here, rather than through a link. When (not if) the link dies, this question loses context. If you do not wish to share your full code permanently, create a [`Minimal, Reproducible Example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you for your kind warnings.

Comment: Your loaded geometry is missing UVs. Try `geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 100, 100 );`

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer, but this is the geometry I loaded from the Three.js official side. I do not know what "geometry is missing UV's " mean. Can you explain it more explicitly so a dummy person such me can understand what it means.

Comment: That will require a tutorial. Here is one. https://discoverthreejs.com/book/first-steps/textures-intro/. You can also get help at https://discourse.threejs.org.